# Generalising button component further

Tags: angular

I have two components:

```
  <app-google-login-button></app-social-login-button>
  <app-facebook-login-button></app-facebook-login-button>
```

`app-facebook-login-button` looks like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-label btn-facebook" (click)="facebookSignIn()"
  *ngIf="!(isMobile | async)?.matches">
  <label>
    <fa-icon [icon]="['fab', 'facebook']" size="xs"></fa-icon>
  </label> Sign in with Facebook
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-label btn-facebook" (click)="mobileFacebookSignIn()"
  *ngIf="(isMobile | async)?.matches">
  <label>
    <fa-icon [icon]="['fab', 'facebook']" size="xs"></fa-icon>
  </label> Sign in with Facebook
</button>
```

`app-google-login-button` looks like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-label btn-google" (click)="googleSignIn()" *ngIf="!(isMobile | async)?.matches">
  <label>
    <fa-icon [icon]="['fab', 'google']" size="xs"></fa-icon>
  </label> Sign in with Google
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-label btn-google" (click)="mobileGoogleSignIn()" *ngIf="(isMobile | async)?.matches">
  <label>
    <fa-icon [icon]="['fab', 'google']" size="xs"></fa-icon>
  </label> Sign in with Google
</button>
```

I'd like to combine both and have a generic `app-social-login-button`. How would the component look like?

Comment: Just calling both component in a template doesn't work?

Comment: Is the only difference for mobile which function is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define an interface that declares the configurable options, but also include a callback function for when the button is clicked. If you don't want to inject a callback for every button, then an alternative is to define a string token like "facebook" and pass that value to a shared service.

```js
export interface SocialButton {
    // button text
    title: string;

    // Font Awesome icon
    icon: any;

    // CSS class for the button
    btn: string;

    // make mobile just a condition of the click
    click: (mobile: boolean) => void;
}
```

You can then pass an object of the above interface as a parameter to the component.

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-social-login-button',
    template: `
        <button type="button"
                [ngClass]="getClass()"
                (click)="click()">
            <label>
                <fa-icon [icon]="options.icon" size="xs"></fa-icon>
            </label> Sign in with {{options.title}}
        </button>`,
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class SocialLoginButtonComponent {

    @Input()
    public options: SocialButton;

    public isMobile: Observable<any>;

    public getClass() {
        return {
            'btn': true,
            'btn-label': true,
            [this.options.btn]: true
        };
    }

    public click() {
        this.isMobile
            .pipe(first())
            .subscribe(value => this.options.click(value));
    }
}
```

You can define a shared service that will create the `SocialButton` options as an array.

```js
@Injectable()
export class SocialButtonService {
    public buttons(): SocialButton[] {
        return [this.faceBook(), this.google()];
    }

    public faceBook(): SocialButton {
        return {title: 'Facebook', icon: ['fab', 'facebook'], btn: 'btb-facebook', click: (m) => this.signIn('facebook', m)}
    }

    public google(): SocialButton {
        return {title: 'Google', icon: ['fab', 'google'], btn: 'btb-google', click: (m) => this.signIn('google', m)}
    }

    public signIn(platform: string, mobile: boolean) {
        // do work
    }
}
```

You can show all the buttons easily now in another component.

```js
@Component({
    template: `
    <app-social-login-button *ngFor="let option of options" [options]="option"></app-social-login-button>
    `
})
export class SocialLoginButtonsComponent {
    public options: SocialButton[];

    public constructor(service: SocialButtonService) {
        this.options = service.buttons();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer, but associating `getClass()`  with `[ngClass]` would keep it triggering in every change detection cycle. This directly impacts the performance .

Comment: @ShashankVivek the component uses `OnPush` change detection so the view is updated *only* when it is marked dirty. You would be correct if that wasn't used, but otherwise it's not an issue. The template is only rendered when the inputs change or you manually mark it dirty.

Comment: Ahhh.. true. Awesome.

Answer (score 2):

From the `HTML` code provided, I can give you some suggestions.

1. Create an `ENUM` which would have list of social media. (*this would restrict the value of social media which can be passed to the component*)
2. Create a component for `app-social-login-button` with `@Input` params as Enum value (either Google or facebook).
3. Inside component `SocialLoginButtonComponent`, check for the passed value and have the `HTML` something like:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-label btn-facebook" (click)="SignIn()"
  *ngIf="!(isMobile | async)?.matches">
  <label>
    <fa-icon [icon]="iconArray" size="xs"></fa-icon>
  </label> Sign in with {{companyName}}
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-label btn-facebook" (click)="SignInWithMobile()"
  *ngIf="(isMobile | async)?.matches">
  <label>
    <fa-icon [icon]="iconArray" size="xs"></fa-icon>
  </label> Sign in with {{companyName}}
</button>
```

in the **component**, check for the `@Input` param and set `companyName`, `iconArray` 
.Configure `SignIn()` and  `SignInWithMobile()` accordingly to call APIs of respective companies.

4. You can also create a `MediaService` which will handle `SignIn` API calls depending on the `Company Name`. Try not to put all the logic in the component itself.